# DAI from Impersonating Accounts

Tags: tokens, contract-deployment, hardhat

i'm running a hadhat node on forked ethereum , i would like to add some usdc and dai to my test account  from an Impersonating Account . How to do that ?. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this article](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/writing-and-compiling-contracts)? Because it mentions USDC and DAI too.

You can just copy the smart contract from here: [DAI](https://etherscan.io/token/0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f) [USDC](https://etherscan.io/token/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48) and deploy it in your local network following the same steps.